# How to understand the logic of this question?

Tags: c, loops, logic

Task:

> Scan 2 numbers outerNumber and innerNumber. Iterate from [0, outerNumber). Inside that loop, iterate from [0, innerNumber). In the inner iteration print the sum of both the iterators.

Note:

```
[x, y] means all numbers from x to y including both x and y.
[x, y) means all numbers from x to y excluding y.
(x, y] means all numbers from x to y excluding x.
(x, y) means all numbers from x to y excluding both x and y.
```

```
Sample Input:
3 5
Expected Output:
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
```

```
Explanation:
outerIterator=0, innerIterator=0 → 0+0 = 0
outerIterator=0, innerIterator=1 → 0+1 = 1
outerIterator=0, innerIterator=2 → 0+2 = 2
outerIterator=0, innerIterator=3 → 0+3 = 3
outerIterator=0, innerIterator=4 → 0+4 = 4
outerIterator=1, innerIterator=0 → 1+0 = 1
outerIterator=1, innerIterator=1 → 1+1 = 2
outerIterator=1, innerIterator=2 → 1+2 = 3
outerIterator=1, innerIterator=3 → 1+3 = 4
outerIterator=1, innerIterator=4 → 1+4 = 5
outerIterator=2, innerIterator=0 → 2+0 = 2
outerIterator=2, innerIterator=1 → 2+1 = 3
outerIterator=2, innerIterator=2 → 2+2 = 4
outerIterator=2, innerIterator=3 → 2+3 = 5
outerIterator=2, innerIterator=4 → 2+4 = 6//
```

This is problem statement of the code and below that explanantion is given, but still I didn't understand how the output is coming.

I would be keen to learn how zeros, 1 and 2 are coming 5 times in Outeriterator and same in InnerIterator

Comment: Looks very clear to me, up to a point where I don't see what needs to be explained.

Comment: Translating this to code - you need a nested for loop. That is - two for loops, one within another. The first for loop iterates from 0 to outer, the second one iterates from `i` to `i + inner`, where `i` is the current iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: "Actually can anyone explain me the explanation part how zeros,1 and 2 are coming 5 times in Outeriterator and same in InnerIterator" - Think of the provided output in terms of columns and rows. Notice how there are 5 columns and 3 rows. That directly corresponds to outer = 3 and inner = 5. Now apply it to code, the outer loop iterates 3 times and the inner loop iterates 5 times.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you be more precise what is puzzling you? You shall take 2 numbers. You shall do 2 nested loops. You shall print the sum of 2 loop counters. You can basicylla directly map the task description to code. The only detail not explicitely mentioned is whether you should add some newlines.

Comment: I think it's hard to describe in words any clearer than the text in the question. I guess only some code can help... take a look here https://ideone.com/UG18Zy

Comment: When quoting a problem, homework, paper, magazine, website, person, etc in a post, always use a quote block. Italics, code formatting or whatever else is semantically wrong. You have a quote, so use quote formatting. In Markdown this is signified by a `>`.  (This has been through several revisions, including two that were wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outer is [0,3), so 0,1,2 is the amount of iterations.

Inner is [0,5), so 0,1,2,3,4 iterations.

Each value from outer requires you to run all the inner values once, so the first time for outer = 0 you will have 0,1,2,3,4 because 0 + [0,5) is 0+0, 0+1, 0+2, 0+3, 0+4.

For outer = 1 you will do the same but add 1 instead of 0.

For outer = 2, same thing 2+0,2+1,2+2,2+3,2+4.

In code should be something close to this:

```
for (i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++){

    for (x = 0; x<5; x++){

        printf i+x;
    }

}
```

Best of luck to you

Comment: yes thanks a lot for ur explanantion and logic and code....its really helped me ...thansks again

Answer (score 1):

Simply, it's nested loop with both outer and inner numbers as the range for both loops. You can implement it easily as:

```
for(out = 0; out < outerNumber; out++){
  for(in = 0; in < innerNumber; in++){
    printf("%d ",out + in);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 yes! i updated it, mistakenly wrote the outerNumber and innerNumber there

Comment: thanks for this implementation ..I run it it worked 95 % and in that printing output we just need Out+in . So i did that but now output is showing like this ""012341234523456"".                And now can u tell how we can convert this output to expected output which involves spaces and new lines which i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Vinayaka you're welcome. Add newline character at the end like:
"...result = %d\n"

Comment: @Vinayaka for the output similar as question, just add a space in the inner print statement at the end and print only newline character in outerloop like:

for(outer loop){
   for(inner loop){
     print("%d ", out + in);
   }
   pirnt("\n");
}

Comment: Really sorry for confusing with actually this comment section made the output in single line and we were wanted like this ......first 5 numbers in 1 line then next 5 numbers in 1 line and last 5 in 1 line ...u can scroll upwards in my question to see the correct expected output ..thanks

Comment: @Vinayaka I updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..yes it worked and expected output was the same as code...again thanks a lot